# How do you make a Chrome App automatically launch in a maximized window?

Tags: json, google-chrome-app

I am making a chrome application and I am wondering how I would make the program automatically run in a maximized window. The manifest.json defaulted to 800x600 but I want it to fill whatever the largest dimensions are. I saw on one of Google's developer pages that you can use maxWidth and maxHeight for this, but I don't know where in the manifest.json to potentially put those values. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This state is not controlled by the manifest.

See the [very first tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app) on apps: window parameters are set in your background script when you create the window with `chrome.app.window.create`.

So, let's go see the documentation for [`chrome.app.window.create()`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create).

It takes a parameter of type `CreateWindowOptions`. Let's see [its documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-CreateWindowOptions).

> (optional) `state`
>
> enum of `"normal"`, `"fullscreen"`, `"maximized"`, or `"minimized"`
>
> The initial state of the window, allowing it to be created already fullscreen, maximized, or minimized. Defaults to 'normal'.

For example:

```
chrome.app.window.create('index.html', { 
  id: 'mainWindow',
  bounds: {width: 800, height: 600},
  state: 'maximized'
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I understand what you're trying to say. I am not sure where to put that `state` call though. This is what is there right now: `chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create(
    'index.html', 
    {
      id: 'mainWindow',
      bounds: {width: 800, height: 600}
      
    }
  );
});`
thanks

Comment: I added an example. _However_, it is very important that you learn to _read and understand_ the documentation. SO will not spoon-feed solutions to you.

Comment: I understand. Thank you so much for your help. This is my first time making a Chrome application, and I had never understood how to put those references in the documentation into code. Thanks for helping me understand that.